# Append issue with python and txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi Im trying to make it so that once a user chooses the name, price and quantity that it will save to the txt file. these are the relevant functions to my issue.

The main issue that keeps occuring is when i go to open the txt and finally write the text into the txt file, nothing happens and it loops back to my first functions except print (print("Please choose a valid action!"))

```
def user_interface_menu():
    while True:
        try:
            print("""
--------------------------------------------------------------
                            Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------
1 - Show one item information
2 - Show all stock information
3 - Add item
4 - Update item
5 - Remove item
6 - Save and exit
7 - Exit without save""")

            user_action = int(input("Action - "))

            if user_action not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7):
                print("Please choose a valid action!")
            elif user_action == 1:
                one_item_information()

            elif user_action == 2:
                all_stock_information()

            elif user_action == 3:
                add_item()

            elif user_action == 4:
                update_item()

            elif user_action == 5:
                remove_item()

            elif user_action == 6:
                save_exit()

            elif user_action == 7:
                exit_no_save()

        except:
            print("Please choose a valid action!")




def add_item():
    try:
        stock_name = input("""
    Please state the name of the product. - """)
        stock_name = str(stock_name)

        price_estimate = input("""
    Please state the estimated price of the product. - """)
        price_estimate = float(price_estimate)

        stock_quantity = input("""
    Please state the quantity of the product. - """)
        stock_quantity = int(stock_quantity)

        print("")
        print("New item Added! - ", end="")
        print(stock_name, price_estimate, stock_quantity)

        with open("store_stock.txt", "a") as f:
            user_addition = input("")
            f.write(stock_name, price_estimate, stock_quantity)
            f.write("\n")
    except:
        print("incorrect")
```

Comment: Does it also print "incorrect"…?

Comment: not that i can see

Comment: Could be indicate an exception occurs. Try add except Exception as error: print(error)

Comment: the code you posted just defines two functions, they are never called. could you post the code you are using to call the user interface menu?

Comment: In general: don’t blankly catch any and all exceptions for large blocks of code and then just ignore them. Be more specific in the type of exceptions you expect, and localize them to specific lines.

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes in your code:

1. 'user_addition = input("")' prompt python to silently wait for an input before doing write()
2. write is not 'print' and you cannot use it the same way

Here is a working write part:

```
    print("")

    with open("store_stock.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(stock_name, price_estimate, stock_quantity))
        f.flush()

    print("New item Added! - ", end="")
    print(stock_name, price_estimate, stock_quantity)
```